# Blender workflow with glb extension for web

Tags: materials, export

I got a big problem. I work as producting 3d modelled objects after I create one of them I need to upload into a web 3d viewer. Now one of them is a semi-transparent plastic spectacular. I created the model in Blender and the material aswell. The material is too complex to bake it to glb instantly. I tried it and as it is expected the web viewer cant handle my material.

Is there a solution with Blender to create a useable material? I looked all over the internet but I didnt find any good solution for this. As I know it can be solve with Substance painter but I never used that before. I would appreciate if someone could find me a solution in Blender.

This is the spectacular I want to export basicly. (The nosepads material haven’t been finished yet but now it doesn’t matter.
The main thing is the temples and frame material. As you can see on the temple where it’s not black it’s semi transparent and the wire inside of the plastic can be seen.
I attach the node too. I know it’s not a glb/gltf compatible this way I created it. But I couldn’t figure anything out with the same result what can be baked. And foremore if I put away the transparency and I bake it without it I put the opacity for alpha blending or cliping or hashed after baking the temple in the background will be seeing first through thecloser parts of the spec. Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you reformulate the question so it's a bit more focused ? I didn't quite catch the exact problem. Thanks

Comment: The problem is I can't create the exact material what can be exported to glb extension what gives back this result in the web based 3d viewer what you can see on the spec picture I attached.

Comment: Yeah and I forget to tell, the material must be a baked texture before export.

Comment: Does your renderer support transparency ? If not, that's not possible, if yes, bake the transparency

Comment: Yes it's supports and I did that and the result was awful.

Comment: What does the transparency map look like ? Could you add it as a screenshot to your post ?

Comment: It was 80% grey and I changed it with photoshop for 20% and that's all. I think it wasn't succesfully export the transparency but! I need the alpha to be exported instead of transparency.

Comment: But moment I bake it and I will show what I got but first I finish other specs first.

Comment: https://imgur.com/6FTr0QR

This was my alpha